# ¿Cómo recuperar una variable por session en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un módulo en java donde mediante un url redirecciono a la una página web, esta página es una validación de usuario y abre la `session` y redirecciona a otra página , lo malo es que  a esta última página no pasa las variables pero si inicia sesión, ahora algo raro es que eso sólo pasa la primera vez, por que si hago clic otra vez al link de mi aplicación java ahí si pasan la variable de la sesión normalmente, es decir solo falla la primera vez que hago clic en el link

**Les dejo el código de donde inicia session**

```
<?php

include 'conexionbd.php';

session_start();


$usuario =  $_GET["usuario"];
$clave = $_GET["clave"];

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
   session_start();

}


$_SESSION["nombre"] =$usuario ;




$consultavalidar1 ="SELECT us.cod_cargo as cod_cargo,uc.cod_centro as codcentro FROM usuario_centro uc
join usuario us on us.dni=uc.dni
where us.usuario='$usuario' AND us.clave='$clave'";


$validar_usuario=mysqli_query($conexion,$consultavalidar1) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));



while($fila = $validar_usuario->fetch_array()){
  $codcentro = $fila['codcentro'];
  $cargo = $fila['cod_cargo'];
}

$_SESSION["cargous"] = $cargo;

echo "sdadas".$_SESSION["nombre"];


if(mysqli_num_rows($validar_usuario)>0){
   echo '<script>

         location.href="inicio.php?codcentro='.$codcentro.'" </script>';

}



  ?>
```

**Esta es la página última dónde no pasa las variables de la sesión**

```
<?php  


 session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
   echo "no hay session";

}else{
    echo " si hay session";
    echo "NOMBRE".$_SESSION['nombre'];
}

?>
```

En esta última si hay sesión pero no me sale la variable `session`.

Comment: el mensaje **echo " si hay session";** te lo imprime?

Comment: si lo imprime , pero la variable no la imprime

Comment: Prueba haciendo un **var_dump($_SESSION);** a ver que información te muestra.

Comment: el session_start(); tiene que estar siempre al principio de todo

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a poner el `session_start();` del primer archivo en la primera línea por delante del `include`? Prueba y me cuentas si cambia o no el comportamiento. Si se han mandado las cabeceras y no se puede establecer correctamente la cookie de sesión el sistema de sesiones no funcionará.

Comment: ya puse la sesion_start() al principio y sigue sin salir la variable ,  cuando hago var_dumps($_sesion) sale array(0) { }

Comment: viendo el código que nos muestras, es difícil entender porque no te sale ya que debe funcionarte sin problemas, que versión de PHP usas?, y como una opción extra, intenta usar otro nombre para tu variable de sesión.

Comment: Error: `<?php
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}` siempre va al principio de todo y ya no lo repites. A mi me parece que el problema esta desde java y desde las paginas intermedias. ¿Puedes poner ese código?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que esté cargando una copia del archivo en caché y por eso no encuentra las variables de sesión, prueba a cargar la página con una variable única para evitar la caché a ver si funciona.

```
echo '<script>
      location.href="inicio.php?codcentro='.$codcentro.'&t='.time().'" </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque no estás comprobando si `$_SESSION['nombre']` está inicializada o no, prueba con lo siguiente

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre'])) 
    { 
       echo "No hay sesión";

    }else{
        echo "Sí hay sesión";
        echo "NOMBRE ".$_SESSION['nombre'];
    }
```

En caso de que no funcione tendrías que comprobar que tu configuración de PHP permita utilizar las variables de sesión, además recuerda que `session_start();` siempre tiene que ir abajo de la etiqueta `<?php`, por lo que deberías de cambiar el orden en el código donde inicias sesión

```
<?php
session_start(); #Siempre al principio del código
include 'conexionbd.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que este bloque de código no hace falta

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
   session_start();

}
```

Ya que al comienzo del archivo estas haciendo un session_start, por lo tanto el array de sesiones $_SESSION está definido. 
Por otra parte, proba en lugar de redireccionar con JS, hacerlo con php del siguiente modo:
header("Location: tuweb.com.ar/blabla.php");

En el archivo destino, donde no te aparece la variable, en las primeras dos lineas coloca esto:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
die();
```

De esta manera comprobas si el array está iniciado en el servidor y si tiene algún valor.